# Time constraint Kanban/Scrum board

Tags: jira, project-management, scrum, kanban

I have the following question.

Often in our project issues stay in progress forever.

To resolve this we would like to introduce a new workflow where if a JIRA issue has been idle for 2 weeks it will automatically have its status set to Postponed.

How can this be implemented in JIRA? I checked the column constraints on the board, but there is no constraint related to time.

Comment: Do you 'complete' each sprint in JIRA at the end? This usually prompts you with any issues that are still open and gives you the opportunity to move them to the next sprint or put them in to the backlog. That would be a good point to mark issues as postponed if they are still open.

Comment: Jira Software has a feature called "Automations". It's a no-code solution for such RPA implementations within Jira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore the arguments how good a workflow and its management is raised by @shippi the solution to this question is explained here.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-questions/ScriptRunner-how-to-change-status-of-an-Issue/qaq-p/628842

Shortly said Jira has ability to execute scripts , they can also be scheduled and executed on regular basis. What needs to be done is a script to be written and scheduled that every day checks how long an issue has been idle and set the appropriate status.

Answer (score 1):

I think **you don't have to build a workflow to mask your problem** with regards to the "*Issues which stay in progress forever*", **but you need to fix it**.

Fixing it means you need to coach the team and support them with various technics to avoid "*never ending stories*". I would suggest to:

- Implement **DOR** (Definition of Ready) - avoid picking up issues which are not yet investigated, groomed and not enough clear to pick up. In our case the story could be added into the sprint just after all external dependencies are sorted out. Use the **INVEST** model which says **INDEPENDENT** How can you commit to deliver issues where you depend on any external team?
- **Slice big stories** - There are plenty of technics how to split large user stories. In general its a bad practice to add a story into the sprint if the estimate shows that it can't be completed. Ideally the right size of the story is "that you have 2,5 story to each dev in single sprint". This doesn't mean that every dev should work on his own story and they can't collaborate, but it means that for e.g. 4 devs for a single sprint 8-10 stories are ideal. (Easier testing, collaboration, better planning, more stable velocity, etc etc..)
- **WIP** (Kanban limit work in progress) - [Putting the 'flow' back in workflow with WIP limits - Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/wip-limits) This is something which is easily configurable in Jira.
- **Show the 'DAYS IN COLUMN' indicator on cards** - This shows a series of dots on each card (up to the width of the card or a maximum of 32), representing the number of days that the issue has been in the column. This could be a useful info for the scrum master to see whether there is any impediment which should be sorted out
- **Don't use blocked** or postponed status. This is just my personal advice. Statuses like blocked/postponed could generate a habit that the issues will be really just postponed instead of removing the impediment and blocker. It is always easier to flag something as blocked as removing the impediment. Its your scrum masters responsibility to remove the obstacles and eliminate the waste.
- **Backlog grooming** - Groom the backlog periodically and if you have problems with the external dependencies flag them in advance. Seek for external dependencies by purpose and identify them as soon as possible. This will give the SM/PO hopefully enough time to deal with them before the issue will be added into the sprint and picked up by the dev team.

Answer (score 0):

Why an issue is sitting idle for two weeks? Is it because of external dependencies or issue is too big to complete in two weeks?

I am not sure about the Jira work flow and if Jira can move it to postponed state. But you can move it back to backlog at the end of the sprint.

But if it happens because the issue is too large to fit in two weeks, then I would recommend to slice it into smaller tasks to fit in sprint.

I hope it helps.